# Why does this Java code behave as it does?

Tags: java

Why does the following code print "Bo-Bo Go-Go", instead of "Bo-Bo Hello, World! Go-Go?

```
public class Test {
    static {
        System.out.print("Bo-Bo ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.print("Hello, World! ");
    }
    static {
        System.out.println("Go-Go ");
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you think it should print? Why?

Answer (score 3):

Because `static` initialization blocks run before the entry-point (both of them), and the second one `exits` thus `main` is never entered.